# Why no SortedMultiset in Google Collections?

Tags: java, guava

[Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) contains the `Multiset` interface and the `TreeMultiset` class, but I was surprised to find that there is no corresponding `SortedMultiset` interface.

Something like that would be very useful for modelling discrete probability distributions.

Before I attempt to implement it myself,  I would like to know if there is a specific reason for leaving it out, e.g. likely violation of `Multiset` or `Collection` invariants, or inherent performance problems etc.

---

**Edit**: I didn't realise it originally but this is actually 3 separate requests:

1. A change to the return type of one method (`TreeMultiset.entrySet`)
2. An new interface to match the existing functionality of `TreeMultiset`
3. A new pair of methods to sum the counts in branches of the tree

Comment: Why do you need to implement it?  How would it be different from `TreeMultiset`?

Comment: It would have equivalents for headSet/tailSet/subSet, which TreeMultiset lacks.  I'm not sure if it is possible to implement these efficiently by extending TreeMultiset.

Comment: Also its `entrySet()` method would return a `SortedSet` instead of a plain `Set`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's just that no one's ever needed it yet, so we haven't written it yet. It's something I'd consider.

Comment: For anyone rereading this question, there's a SortedMultiset as of version 11.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMultiset.elementSet() returns a SortedSet, which might provide some of the functionality you want.

ETA: finnw, the SortedMultiset methods you're requesting wouldn't provide a significantly faster answer to the question "how many elements in my Multiset are less than 42?"   The TreeMultiset implementation would still have to iterate across the multiset entries and sum the counts of the relevant elements.

Comment: Almost.  One thing it can't do efficiently is answer "how many elements in my Multiset<Integer> are less than 42?"  The element set (and its headSet/tailSet methods) will give you the number of distinct values less than 42, but not the number of elements.