# Why doesn't Google Collections support MultiKeyMap like Apache Collections?

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons

Is the decision by Google similar to the one for `SortedMultiSet` [(stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331174/why-no-sortedmultiset-in-google-collections)
or is it because there is no use of `MultiKeyMap`?

I am aware that an alternate for `MultiKeyMap` can be to use a custom Class as a key which contains the multiple keys as its class members. On the contrary, I like the concept of specifying multiple keys when calling the get of the `MultiKeyMap`.

Apache's version of `MultiKeyMap` is great but I'm severely missing Generics and therefore looked into Google Collections for a modern implementation of it. If someone has any idea why Google hasn't supported it yet or there's a better alternative for it then please respond.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a very nice implementation of a two-tiered map , which we call a "table" (K1 is the "row key" and K2 is the "column key"), and we just haven't gotten it released yet.  Past two keys, though, is diminishing returns.

Comment: great to have official google-collection guy responding :)
Can I have a sneak peak into this 'table' data structure?
And why not have a 3-tiered and 4-tiered map?

Comment: @kevin-bourrillion has this 2-tiered map been released yet?

Comment: yes, as the most-upvoted answer here points out. My answer should be unaccepted.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but can you explain why " Past two keys, though, is diminishing returns."?

Answer (score 11):

FYI, the accepted answer was answered in March 2010, but as of September 2010 Guava included `Table`.

- [Collections explained - Table](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table)
- [Tables utility class](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Tables)
- [Table javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)

Comment: can you edit the accepted answer with the updated information you provided here?

Comment: @MonisIqbal You're not supposed to do that. Here is [one post among many on Meta on this topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320293/1768232). If you don't like the accepted answer, downvote it. If you do like mine, upvote it, that's what the buttons are for. But you should not completely content-edit another's answer, ever, the editing feature is for improvements that don't change content.

Answer (score 3):

I think generics might be the showstopper for implementation here. If you look at just the Map interface there are generic specifiers for the key type (K) and the value type (V). I don't believe it would be possible to specify it using generics easily without separating the implementations into multiple classes (one for each number of key components).

You would need a class for each:

```
MultiKeyMap2<K1,K2,V>
MultiKeyMap3<K1,K2,K3,V>
MultiKeyMap4<K1,K2,K3,K4,V>
MultiKeyMap5<K1,K2,K3,K4,K5,V>
```

The underlying implementation is basically doing what you suggest (using a custom class).  However, it doesn't formally create a class for it, everything is inlined. It's really an implementation detail.  But to use the Google collections a custom class to perform the same thing would operate much the same way I'm sure to implement hashCode() and equals().